# SQL CE over a network share

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have seen this question asked previously but can not find a clear explanation of what is/isn't possible and what workarounds migth be available.

I have an existing C# application that uses SQL CE to store local information. This database is only accessed by a single application and is stored in the user's appdata folder.

Some environments have the appdata folder redirected to a network share which causes SQL CE to throw an exception: "Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region."

I have read that SQL CE 3.5 SP2 is supposed to allow connections to network shares again, and that SP1 does not, however I have not been able to get it to work. Has anybody had any success getting any version of SQL CE to work over a network share? And if so, what version/code did you use to get it to work?

I have tried using mode=Exclusive in the connection string with no luck.

Or alternatively, has anybody found a different workaround? The data needs to be stored in the user's profile as it is specific per user and should not be accessible by any other user on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the application to use SQL Express with local user instances which worked, but it created too many deployment issues for our customers. I ended up having to write a layer to use Access MDBs while we look at different database options.

My suggestion for writing desktop applications is DO NOT use SQL express or SQL CE for local storage.

Answer (score 2):

I've used SQL CE 3.5 successfully on a networked drive with instances of an application running simultaneously on two networked computers. I was able to update records in the database from both locations.

I'm not sure what would happen if two users accessed the same record at the same time, however this is unlikely in my situation. Just include the database location in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a folder that is not redirected.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way to ensure that where I am writing to is not redirected. The user's folder is redirected, there is nowhere else to store the data per user.

Comment: In the appdata folder on my Win7 PC, is see Local, LocalLOw and Roaming folders - I am sure they are not all redirected.

Comment: Windows XP does not have Local/Roaming etc, it has a single Application Data folder that is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Compact is a single-user, in-process database engine.

Have you tried to put sqlce DB on a shared folder and set its datasource where it is located?

Something like:

```
"Data Source=\\MySharedfolder\\DB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Comment: SQL Express is not an option. The application requires a database per logged in user. The end user does not have the ability to install SQL Express on the server. Everything must run on the user's machine. I don't see how SQL Express is possible here. Also, as mentioned, the database is stored in the user's appdata folder that is being silently redirected to a network share.