# Connect WPF app to SQL Server CE 3.5 file shared on LAN

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, connection-string

How can I connect my C# WPF app to a SQL Server CE 3.5 `.sdf` file, placed on a shared location on LAN? I couldn't figure out what value to be used as `Data Source` in the connection string. I have a PC on my LAN, with name `RT-PC`, and it has a shared folder, named `RSDB-prod`. I tried to connect using following string:

```
<add name="RSEntitiesLan" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.RsModelLan.csdl|res://*/Model.RsModelLan.ssdl|res://*/Model.RsModelLan.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=\\RT-PC\RSDB-prod\RsCompact.sdf;Password=123&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here, `Password=123` is the password of the `RsCompact.sdf` file.

I also tried supplying `User Id` section, but It also did not work.

I tried to look for the solution and looked at several SO posts, like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744134/connection-string-with-an-sql-server-ce-database), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157368/connecting-c-sharp-to-sql-server-compact-database), and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307593/sql-ce-over-a-network-share), but none discussed about `LAN` scenario as I require. I have following concerns/questions.

**Questions:**

- How can I connect to a SQL Server CE 3.5 file, located on shared LAN PC from my WPF app?
- How to change connection strings accordingly, when LAN PC has logon username and password set? My `.sdf` db file also has password
- I have a PC on LAN, that has username, but no password. Would it be possible to connect that PC? If so, how?

Other info:

- This is a WPF app, which need to store/retrieve data on/from `.sdf` file at server PC on LAN. When that PC is connected to internet, all data is copied to remote SQL Server db.
- Above connection string works fine, if I change the DataSource to the same PC as `C:\dbfile\xyz.sdf` for instance. Now I need to deploy this system, so need to modify connection string accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "not work" mean?

Using SQL Compact for this scenario is not supported, you should use SQL Server Express instead

Comment: For that specific point, it threw an exception, saying something like _invalid property User Id for this . . ._
Thank you Erik, I was expecting your answer on this post.

Comment: So there is not chance I can achieve my goal using SQL CE, in my scenario? I am at the end of the app, and used SQL CE throughout. :| is there any workaround possible?

Comment: Nope, you should have clarified this requirement at the beginning of your project

Comment: But you can use my tools to easily migrate to sql server

Comment: Yes, I should have done that. Thank you. The tool you are referring here is _SQL CE & SQLite Toolbox_, right?

Comment: Plus, I would like to know, if there is any alternative to SQL Server Express in my case?

Comment: Yes, there are other relational database servers from other companies than Microsoft, but I would recommend SQL Server, which is a high quality product, And Express edition is free.

Comment: Erik, I would like to know one more thing. I am using Entity Frame with this SQL CE db. After migration to SQL Server Express, would it cause any mapping issues? Actually I'm concerned about the template which EF generates, if it is gona be same for mapping from SQL CE and SQL Express.

Comment: You may have to change the ProviderManifesttoken, otherwise it should work as expected